# OpenAPI 3.0 cannot recognize JSR 303 @Size annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi

I created a project according to this [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation) and [official document](https://springdoc.org/)

my POJO:

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Subscription {
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private String id;
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private String name;
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private String email;
}
```

my controller:

```java
@RestController
public class IndexController {

    @PostMapping("/index")
    public String index(@RequestBody Subscription subscription) {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

pom.xml

```xml
        <!-- openapi3 -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

spring version

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

According the above documents the generated swagger supposed to have `MinLength` and `MaxLength` limitation but it doesn't.

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Subscription:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
        email:
          type: string
```

Can anyone help? is there anything I missed?